# SQLite select query to string

Tags: android, sqlite, persistent-storage

I'm not able to add read data from the following SQLite select query function. I have a table with 3 columns, namely driverID, driversName, driversNo.

It's supposed to return a simple string but alas.

```
public String readDrivers() {
    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.PROFILE_TABLE_NAME, necessaryColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Log.v("TEST", Integer.toString(cursor.getCount()));
        Log.v("TEST", cursor.getColumnName(0));
        Log.v("TEST", cursor.getColumnName(1));
        Log.v("TEST", cursor.getString(0));
        Log.v("TEST", cursor.getString(1));
    }

    String returnString = cursor.getString(0) + cursor.getString(1);
    return returnString;
}
```

Below are the most recent results from LogCat. The last two logs don't show, for some strange reason.

```
08-04 20:27:35.271: V/TEST(25126): 1
08-04 20:27:35.271: V/TEST(25126): driversName
08-04 20:27:35.271: V/TEST(25126): driversNo
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The rest of the code is based on this tut http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: So what is it returning?? Are you getting any errors?  If so, post your LOGCAT.

Comment: Let me suggest you using `column names`, instead of column indexes (which are **0 based**), since you don't know in which order the column will be put in your cursor.

Comment: I'm getting no errors, just an empty textview. I have changed also changed to column names but not solution either.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you provided your table structure, but in any case, some info that might help:

Cursor starts from position -1 when not null.

A good way to read the cursor would be

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    ...
}
```

Also,

```
String returnString = cursor.getString(1) + cursor.getString(2);
```

The above code will concatenate column index 1 and column index 2 (please note that indexes start from 0), from first row returned from your query.

Edit:
Then something as the following should work fine.

```
public String readDrivers() {
    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.PROFILE_TABLE_NAME, necessaryColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        list.add(cursor.getString(1) + cursor.getString(2));
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: My table has three columns, namely driverID, driverName, driverNo. I intended to concatenate the two strings.

Comment: The edit above will return you a list of the concatenated drivers